# Adaptor/convertor parts for HDDs?

Tags: macbook-pro, hardware, ibook

I decided to swap my early 2011 MacBook Pro's HDD for a SSD and put that HDD in my G4 iBook. However, all of the guides I found used iBooks with an orange, cord-like HDD port (I don't know if port is the right word) like the one in my MBP. My iBook doesn't have such an port.

[image: iBook's HDD port and connector]

The part I am holding was connected to the iBook's HDD, allowing it connect the port.

My MBP HDD does not fit the adapter(?) piece or the HDD port:
[image]

My question(s): what these parts are actually called? Without the right vocabulary I'm having a hard time answering other questions like: Where can I get one? Do they make ones that would allow me to put the MBP HDD into the iBook?

Comment: The hard-drive doesn't actually need to be replaced, I was going to swap them because I thought I could.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference is the HDD connectors. The iBook G4 uses an IDE (aka PATA) connector, whereas the MBP uses SATA. Unfortunately during a quick google search I wasn't able to find a SATA to IDE adapter that would fit inside the laptop case. It's probably worth looking for second-hand IDE hard drives or contacting someone at Apple to see if they have a better idea. If you want to buy a drive, try starting here: [Ebay IDE laptop drives](http://www.ebay.com/bhp/ide-laptop-hard-drive). Let me know if you have any questions or if I got any of my information wrong.

Comment: I do have 1 question: Do you think it's possible to replace the iBooks CD drive--which I don't use--with the SATA/IDE adapter (I don't think I'm using the right words for a google search because I'm seeing a lot of links for replacing the HDD with a SSD)?

Comment: @boredrandom good question! I don't know and if I were you I might not go that route - it would be more effort than it's worth, I think. What I would do in your case is get a small used HDD for inside the computer (for your operating system, and put your documents on the HDD from the MBP you have now. Get a USB cord and hard drive enclosure (something like the one linked at the end) to store documents on (https://www.amazon.com/dp/B00OJ3UJ2S/ref=cm_sw_r_cp_api_RVtLxb6W11XEM)

Comment: If the connection is PATA, the transfer rate will be FAR FAR below that of an SSD.  You'll gain almost no benefit with an SSD being converted to a PATA connection.

Answer (score 1):

There two basic hard disk interfaces. The legacy interface is called ATA, which transfers bits in parallel. This is probably what you found in your G4 iBook. I say this because the [Everything Mac](http://www.everymac.com/systems/apple/ibook/index-ibook.html) site show this type of interface for all G4 iBooks.

The new interface is called SATA, which transfers bits in serial. This is what is used in your 2011 MacBook Pro. This drive will not fit your G4 iBook. You could try to find an adaptor, but most likely there will not be enough space for such an adaptor in your iBook.

To determine the requirements for a replacement drive, you would have to include more information about your iBook model/year and/or the brand and model number of the drive.

> Note: Parallel ATA drives are also referred to as IDE and PATA drives.